# ENFILE error due to making too many Axios requests

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

I have an array list of 7000 users.

For each of the 7000 users, I need to make a GET request.

My code runs but I am getting the following error for a lot of the requests:

```
"ENFILE"
"ENFILE"
"connect"
"10.10.12.72"
80
```

I believe I need to throttle the requests but not sure exactly how to go about it.

Here's the code:

**users is an array of 7000 entries.**

```
  users.forEach((user) => {
    axios({
      url: getUserRolesEndpoint + `${user.userId}`,
      method: 'get',
      timeout: 10000,
    })
    .then((response) => {
        // I do something with the response
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the libary 'limiter' fixed my issue:

```
 const RateLimiter = require('limiter').RateLimiter;
 const limiter = new RateLimiter(5, 'second');

 users.forEach((user) => {
    limiter.removeTokens(1, (errd, remainingRequests) => {
       axios({
         url: getUserRolesEndpoint + `${user.userId}`,
         method: 'get',
         timeout: 10000,
       })
       .then((response) => {
          // I do something with the response
       });
    });
 });
```